# What is the PDO equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

How can security with PDO or what is the equivalent PDO this secure function?

```
function secure($string){
  return(mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($string))));
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to prevent SQL injection? Use prepared statements then.

Comment: Yes, I did some research but could not find a solution to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Man PHP: you have to use the function PDO::quote()

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: It should be a very rare circumstance that you're using `PDO::quote()` instead of a prepared statement. Important to note though, that this is _not_ a direct equivalent function to `mysql_real_escape_string()`, because `PDO::quote()` both escapes internally and places outer quotes on the string: From the linked docs "_PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and escapes special characters_"